# Can I rerun a Django request?

Tags: django, mongodb, request, zodb

I'm using a key-value store for Django. To manage conflict errors for concurrent processes accessing the same objects, I need to rerun whole Django requests if the final commit fails.

How do I do this? Can I somehow initiate the rerun inside a `middleware.process_response`?

Comment: Have you tried to save the request object in a local variable?

Comment: Hi, and what should I do with the variable afterwards?

Comment: I mean to say save it either in django session or some local variable, and rerun with these parameters if request fails?